# List with multiple checkboxes

Tags: user-interface, checkbox, flask, jinja2

I am trying to create my first `flask` based website. So i have created a list which has two fields `text` and `status`. I will be displaying this in a table with `text` as label and `status` as `checkbox`.

What I want to do that for each checkbox, I want to capture the change status and update it at server.

I am thinking to create each `text`:`status` in a form. But i am unable to grasp that how would it go back, what field would it bind too and how would i make sure that i am getting correct checkbox id.

This is what i am doing right now

```
  {% for checklist_entry in dashboard_items %}
    <label class="checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" value={{checklist_entry.entry_id}}>
      {{checklist_entry.text}}
    </label>
  {% endfor %}
```

How can i setup ajax request to update it via ajax? And what do i need at server side?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a submit button that posts to your server.

If you want to update it on the table without reloading the page, bind your checkbox's onClick event and use Ajax to send the request to your server and append the data to the table.